# Does Rebus support batch sending

Tags: rebus

Is it possible to batch Rebus messages (using Azure Servicebus) ? 
The reason is that we are going to send a lot of message to save log events and want to batch up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While old versions of Rebus did have a batch API for wrapping up multiple logical messages inside one single transport message, that functionality turned out to bring very little advantage at the expense of increased complexity in many places.

If you want to send batches of messages, I suggest you simply code your own message batch message, something like

```
public class BatchOfLogEvents
{
    public BatchOfLogEvents(IEnumerable<LogEvent> logEvents)
    {
        LogEvents = logEvents.ToArray();
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<LogEvent> LogEvents { get; }
}
```

and then you send that and create a handler for it in the other end.

---

Update regarding Azure Service Bus: Please remember that Azure Service Bus has a [256 kB maximum message size (or 1MB if you're on Premium)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas).

Also: If you have not done so already, you can probably benefit from enabling GZip compression of messages by going

```
.Options(o => o.EnableCompression())
```

in your Rebus configurations.